# Unknown column 'column_name' in 'on clause' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two table like bellow

```
CREATE TABLE "accounts" (
    "name"      TEXT,
    "number"    INTEGER,
    "normal"    INTEGER
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "transactions"
  (
     "id"        INTEGER, 
     "date"      TEXT,
     "amount"    REAL,
     "account"   INTEGER,
     "direction" INTEGER
  )
```

when I run this query it shown Unknown column 'a' in 'on clause'

Query is -

```
select
   ((account / 100) * 100) as a,
   name,
   sum(amount * direction * normal) as balance
 from
   transactions
   left join accounts on a = accounts.number
 group by
   name
order by
  a,
  name;
```

I tried a lot by changing queries and unable to solve that.

Comment: And if you change the order by from `a` to `((account / 100) * 100)` what happens ?

Comment: Double quotes enclosing table and column names are not valid in mysql and the create statements are missing terminators so are you really using mysql?

Comment: Note the select happens after the from/jion in the order of execution so nothing in the select is available in the join

Comment: What's the point of writing `account / 100 * 100`? The division and multiplication cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a column alias in the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses in the same query. So you need to repeat the expression.

```
select
   ((account / 100) * 100) as a,
   name,
   sum(amount * direction * normal) as balance
 from
   transactions
   left join accounts on a = ((account / 100) * 100)
 group by
   name
order by
  a,
  name;
```